# Exception is in the round blue line in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Exception is in the round blue line.

[image: 1]

Comment: map["unitePrice"] = unitePrice; insteadOf  map[unitePrice] = unitePrice;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mistake is on Line 12, where you're passing a double as a key to look up a value for. Change it to `map['unitPrice'] = unitePrice;`

Comment: I did it but still going

Comment: Can you edit your post and copy paste your code? That makes it easier to help you out here.

Comment: thank for tour help ı solve this